# How to replace dash(-) with space in .htaccess?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

How to replace dash(-) with space in htaccess ?

I want to add spaces to replace dash in url in htaccess, I have tried several ways but always end up with an opposite answers.

Comment: what is your current url and what have you tried please post it in question.

Comment: http://mageisland.com/projects/express-new/about-us.html
this is my url

Comment: i want it like this 
http://mageisland.com/projects/express new/about us.html

Comment: why would you wanna do that?